# Semantic and non Semantic elements

Tags: html

Is `<a>` tag is a semantic or non semantic element. By definition of semantic element it feels like `<a>` should be a semantic element. Can somebody explain me how we categorize the elements into semantic and non semantic

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/semantic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Semantics is the study of the meanings of words and phrases in a language.
>
> Semantic elements = elements with meaning.
>
> A semantic element clearly describes its meaning to both the browser and the developer.
>   Examples of non-semantic elements: `<div>` and `<span>` - Tells nothing about its content.
>   Examples of semantic elements: `<form>`, `<table>`, and `<article>` - Clearly defines its content.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

`<a>` is non-semantic element

Comment: for example if a developer see's <a> tag he/she clearly understands that it is a link . Or you mean to say that the by reading the tag name a layman can understand its content.

Comment: A semantic element is understandable to the simple person.

„clearly describes its meaning to both the browser and the developer“

Answer (score 1):

The IT Semantic: picking a variable name which is logical, and describes its purpose,

Since we are name everything in IT: servers, tables, classes, columns, functions and variables these mechanisms are not arbitrary, if they are chosen right the system is arguably more intuitive, for an English speaker, or same language speaker.

HTML has various semantic, and infamously counter intuitive tag names, due to the requirement it must be backwards compatible.

The `<A>` tag should be `<LINK>` unless the purpose was to conserve bits, there is no reason to make the fundamental purpose of HTML (hyperlinks) 1 character long, and why not `<L>`?

To convey meaning, semantic names should probably not be abbreviated, a verb (get, or set) for a function and a noun for an entity.